# What is the time complexity of lower()/higher() of TreeSet in Java?

Tags: java

I know the time complexity of basic operations such as add, get is O(logn). But I didn't found the detail of lower() and higher(). So, what is the time complexity of lower() and higher() of TreeSet in Java?

Comment: Also see [Computational Complexity of TreeSet methods in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14379515/computational-complexity-of-treeset-methods-in-java)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

TreeSet is backed by an implementation of NavigableMap called TreeMap.  The code ultimately called when computing lower() on TreeSet is lowerEntry() on TreeMap.

```
/**
 * Returns the entry for the greatest key less than the specified key; if
 * no such entry exists (i.e., the least key in the Tree is greater than
 * the specified key), returns {@code null}.
 */
final Entry<K,V> getLowerEntry(K key) {
    Entry<K,V> p = root;
    while (p != null) {
        int cmp = compare(key, p.key);
        if (cmp > 0) {
            if (p.right != null)
                p = p.right;
            else
                return p;
        } else {
            if (p.left != null) {
                p = p.left;
            } else {
                Entry<K,V> parent = p.parent;
                Entry<K,V> ch = p;
                while (parent != null && ch == parent.left) {
                    ch = parent;
                    parent = parent.parent;
                }
                return parent;
            }
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Looking at this code, it looks like with each iteration of the while loop, every branch either returns or traverse one level of the tree.  Since Tree Map should have `log(n)` levels, the entire method has `O(log(n))` complexity.

Answer (score 1):

In Java TreeSet and TreeMap is a red-black (balanced) binary search tree(BST). And when you are searching (methods: `lower()` and `higher()` are actually searching) over the red-black BST time-complexity is going to be 2 log N.

So the time complexity of both methods is O (log N).

Answer (score 0):

It's the same as `get()`, O(log n).

`lower()` or `higher()` does a `get()`; then it does a `get()` again to find the next (lower or higher) node.  Since constants like 2 drop out of big-O notation, it's just O(log n) again.

Answer (score 0):

It's not specified in the docs, but the implementation — at least for OpenJDK 8 — is O(log n).

TreeSet uses TreeMap under the hood for its operations (with the set's elements stored as the map's keys), and in particular lower() [delegates straight to TreeMap::lowerKey](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/java/util/TreeSet.java#TreeSet.lower%28java.lang.Object%29) (the `m` field is typed as NavigableMap, but if you look at the constructors you'll see that it's always TreeMap).

[TreeMap::lowerKey](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/java/util/TreeMap.java#TreeMap.lowerKey%28java.lang.Object%29), in turn, really comes down to a call to [getLowerEntry](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/java/util/TreeMap.java#TreeMap.getLowerEntry%28java.lang.Object%29), which starts at the root and then finds the appropriate entry; this is O(log n) in any binary search tree (such as the red-black tree that TreeMap uses).

TreeSet::higher() uses a similar delegation, and has the same performance characteristics.

Comment: Is there a data strucure with linked elements, so we can do it in O(1)?

Comment: @NathanB The thing that takes log n time is finding the node, not constructing the subtree from it.