# What is the runtime of removing a range of values in Java Treeset?

Tags: java, data-structures, tree, binary-search-tree, treeset

I want to remove values between a certain range in a TreeSet as follows:

```java
TreeSet<Integer> ts = new TreeSet<Integer>();

for(int i = 0; i < (int)1e7; i++){
    ts.add((int)(Math.random() * 1e9));
}

System.out.println("ts: " + ts.size());
SortedSet<Integer> s = ts.subSet(500, (int)8e8);
s.clear();
System.out.println("ts: " + ts.size());
```

What is the runtime of this operation?

Is it `O(log(n))` or `O(n)`? I found some [references](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14379515/computational-complexity-of-treeset-methods-in-java) stating that the `subSet()` operation takes `log(n)`. I've also read that the `clear()` operation is `O(1)`, but wouldn't the individual nodes to be cleared, making it potentially `O(n)`?

Comment: Creating a `subSet` should be O(1), since it does not copy any elements, but simply returns a view of the backing set. I don't know how your linked answer came to the conclusion that it would be O(log n)

Comment: @OldDogProgrammer, yes I've realized that and updated the example to reflect such concerns. My question still remains in the general case when the Treeset / subset both have O(n) elements. Also aware of the autoboxing, but more interested in the Treeset internals.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Calling `TreSet#subSet` returns a *view* of the original collection. Creating this view is O(1). No elements are copied when creating the subset view. Most operations on the view are delegated to the underlying, original collection.

`clear()` however is an exception. Calling `clear` on a `TreeSet` (or `TreeMap`, really) is O(1), since it only sets the size to 0 and clears the root node.

This is not possible for a subset view of the `TreeSet`, which needs to remove all elements in the view one-by-one, delegating to the `AbstractCollection#clear` method, which is [implemented as follows](https://github.com/AdoptOpenJDK/openjdk-jdk11/blob/master/src/java.base/share/classes/java/util/AbstractCollection.java#L443):

```
public void clear() {
    Iterator<E> it = iterator();
    while (it.hasNext()) {
        it.next();
        it.remove();
    }
}
```

Rmeoving a single item from the red-black-tree implementation of `TreeMap` (of which `TreeSet` is only a wrapper) is O(log(n)). **Removing N items, which needs to be done for a subset view, is therefore O(n * log(n))**.

Comment: Why is this not true for a subset?

Comment: I did some digging (https://github.com/AdoptOpenJDK/openjdk-jdk11/blob/master/src/java.base/share/classes/java/util/TreeSet.java#L323), and it looks like the subset is implemented using a Treeset, which wouldn't go to the AbstractCollection#clear method.

Comment: @Abundance it's not true because the subset cannot simply say "size = 0", because it does not have a size. It's a view on the original set. Changes to the original set become visible in the subset and vice-versa. To clear a subset, you have to remove all elements of the subset from the original set. This is only possible by calling `remove(element)` in a loop. The subset is implement by wrapping a `subMap` (there's a package-private special constructor). The submap delegates to clearing AbstractCollection. I confirmed with a debugger, feel free to do the same :)