# Difference between PriorityQueue and TreeSet in Java?

Tags: java, data-structures, tree

I am trying to understand when to use the two data structures. As far as I have understood the `PriorityQueue` is also implemented as a tree as the documentation states that the average time for insert, remove and contains is O(log(n)). The `TreeSet` also provides the same time complexity. Plus both of them are unsynchorized implementation. And I can write comparator for them to act like min heap or max heap.

Can some one point out in what conditions I use these two sets?

Answer (score 44):

When you want a queue, use a PriorityQueue. When you want a Set, use a TreeSet. A TreeSet has unique elements, and doesn't offer the API of a Queue. A Queue doesn't offer the API of a Set, and allows multiple equal elements.

Comment: Other than duplicate elements both are preserving the same ordering? or any other differences other API methods and duplicate support?